# Launch Daemon Script on Jailbroken iOS

Tags: ios, ios9, jailbreak

Is it possible to run a script through a launch daemon for an **indefinite** amount of time on jailbroken iOS 9? Would iOS 9 eventually kill a launch daemon that runs a script indefinitely, or would it just let the script keep running? Would a launch daemon be a feasible way of running said script on an iPhone?

Answer (score 2):

`Launchd` doesn't do anything special if you didn't ask it to. It will parse your plist, launch the binary and that's it. The daemon can run for as long as it wants. You can check out Cydia auto-install script at `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.saurik.Cydia.Startup.plist`. Using that plist as a reference you can launch your script that will run indefinitely. `Launchd` will not do anything to it.

There're other components that can kill your process but there're ways to prevent that. For example, if memory starts running low the kernel will start killing processes and your daemon might be killed as well. That kernel component is called `jetsam`. All processes have some `jetsam` priority and memory limit associated with them and depending on that they will or will not be killed when memory runs low. You can read about that [here](http://newosxbook.com/articles/MemoryPressure.html). You can also just tell `launchd` to relaunch your process automatically if that fits your case.